# Generate a variable for an entire household based on another variable for cross sectional data

Tags: variables, stata

I have a dataset on various households. Each household has various individuals. I want to take one entry(individual) for a specific variable and apply it to the entire household. Finally I want to perform regression on the household data and ignore the individuals. Eg:

Household id | Individual id | Variable 1

H1               |  A1             |a

H1                | A2             | .

H1                | A3             | a

H1                | A4             | a

H2                | A1             | B

H2                | A2             | .

H3                | A1             | B

H3                | A2             | a

H3                | A3             | .

H3                | A4             | a

H3                 |  A5             |  .

H3                 | A6            | .

I want to create a data where :

Household id  Variable 1

H1              | a

H2              | B

H3              | B
[EDIT : it is possible to do it through egen. I was trying to approach it through nested loops.

```
> foreach h in household_id{  
>       local d = 0  
>       local e = 0  
>       foreach i in individual_id{  
>       replace `d' = 1  if var1 == 1  
>       replace `e' = 2  if var1 == 2  
>       }  
>   foreach i in individual_id{  
>       replace a = 1 if `d' == 1  
>       replace a = 2 if `e' == 2  
>       }  
>       }
```

Here a is another variable which I will directly use to replace var1. The code gives an error :

> ```
> 0 invalid name
> ```

What are the corrections required in my code? Is there a fundamental flaw in my usage of local macros? Using tempvar didn't help either.

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service in which we write code for you. Please show some effort in trying to write code.

Comment: `help bysort` and `help egen` might be good first steps here

Comment: @Eric  egen works. Thanks for the help. I have been trying to use nested loops ;however, I was still struggling with the local variables I generated.

Comment: Good that you are writing code. But you need to show what it is to get comments on it!

Comment: @NickCox apologies for not doing it earlier.  I am new to Stackoverflow. I have added the code. Kindly take a look.

Comment: Being new is fine; everyone is a beginner at the beginning. I've suggested some resources to study. At present this is a poor question and still needs much improvement. You may be trying to translate from some other software which works quite differently.

Answer (score 0):

The code shown is very confused.

A loop over a single entity that is never referred to inside the loop is legal but just is equivalent to the statements inside, executed once.

Notice that you never refer to the local macros `h` or `i` within your loops.

Thus your code is equivalent to

```
local d = 0  
local e = 0  
replace `d' = 1  if var1 == 1  
replace `e' = 2  if var1 == 2  
replace a = 1 if `d' == 1  
replace a = 2 if `e' == 2
```

That fails when the local macro `d` is first replaced by its contents, which results in

```
replace 0 = 1 if var1 == 1
```

and the error message is correct because `0` is not a valid variable name. The next statement would raise the same problem.

Stata never gets as far as testing

```
... if 0 == 1 

... if 0 == 2
```

and those statements, although legal, would do nothing because the conditions will never be satisfied.

So far, so negative. I can't suggest code positively because I don't understand what you want to do. What you have posted doesn't look like real or realistic data. I suggest that you look at http://www.statalist.org/forums/help#stata which suggests how to post Stata data examples (and so is relevant here) and also at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (which does lay down the standard here).